# Why does my nbody solver have the earth moving in a straight line instead of an orbit?

Tags: python, physics

I'm making an Nbody solver for a physics project, and I've gotten to the point where I'm plotting the position of the Earth around the Sun. When I do this, however, the earth just travels away from the sun in a straight line, and does not perform an orbit. Is there something I'm missing with my acceleration calculation thats causing this? Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import astropy.units as u 
import astropy.constants as c 
import sys 
import time
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#making a class for Celestial Objects
class CelestialObjects():
    def __init__(self,mass,pos_vec,vel_vec,name=None, has_units=True):
        self.name=name
        self.has_units=has_units
        if self.has_units:
            self.mass=mass.cgs
            self.pos=pos_vec.cgs.value
            self.vel=vel_vec.cgs.value
        else:
            self.mass=mass 
            #3d array for position of body in 3d space in AU
            self.pos=pos_vec 
            #3d array for velocity of body in 3d space in km/s
            self.vel=vel_vec
        
    def return_vec(self):
        return np.concatenate((self.pos,self.vel))
    def return_name(self):
        return self.name
    def return_mass(self):
        if self.has_units:
            return self.mass.cgs.value
        else:
            return self.mass
  

#set up first instance of a celestial object, Earth
Earth=CelestialObjects(name='Earth',
                       pos_vec=np.array([0,1,0])*u.AU,
                       vel_vec=np.array([0,30,0])*u.km/u.s,
                       mass=1.0*c.M_earth)
#set up second instance of a celestial object, the Sun
Sun=CelestialObjects(name='Sun',
                     pos_vec=np.array([0,0,0])*u.AU,
                     vel_vec=np.array([0,0,0])*u.km/u.s,
                     mass=1*u.Msun)
bodies=[Earth,Sun]

#making a class for system
class Simulation():
    def __init__(self,bodies,has_units=True):
        self.has_units=has_units
        self.bodies=bodies
        self.Nbodies=len(self.bodies)
        self.Ndim=6
        self.quant_vec=np.concatenate(np.array([i.return_vec() for i in self.bodies]))
        self.mass_vec=np.array([i.return_mass() for i in self.bodies])
        self.name_vec=[i.return_name() for i in self.bodies]
        
    def set_diff_eqs(self,calc_diff_eqs,**kwargs):
        self.diff_eqs_kwargs=kwargs
        self.calc_diff_eqs=calc_diff_eqs
    
    def rk4(self,t,dt):
        k1= dt* self.calc_diff_eqs(t,self.quant_vec,self.mass_vec,**self.diff_eqs_kwargs)
        k2=dt*self.calc_diff_eqs(t+dt*0.5,self.quant_vec+0.5*k1,self.mass_vec,**self.diff_eqs_kwargs)
        k3=dt*self.calc_diff_eqs(t+dt*0.5,self.quant_vec+0.5*k2,self.mass_vec,**self.diff_eqs_kwargs)
        k4=dt*self.calc_diff_eqs(t+dt,self.quant_vec+k3,self.mass_vec,**self.diff_eqs_kwargs)
        
        y_new=self.quant_vec+((k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6)
        return y_new
    
    def run(self,T,dt,t0=0):
        if not hasattr(self,'calc_diff_eqs'):
            raise AttributeError('You must set a diff eq solver first.')
        if self.has_units:
            try:
                _=t0.unit
            except:
                t0=(t0*T.unit).cgs.value
            T=T.cgs.value
            dt=dt.cgs.value
        
        self.history=[self.quant_vec]
        clock_time=t0
        nsteps=int((T-t0)/dt)
        start_time=time.time()
        for step in range(nsteps):
            sys.stdout.flush()
            sys.stdout.write('Integrating: step = {}/{}| Simulation Time = {}'.format(step,nsteps,round(clock_time,3))+'\r')
            y_new=self.rk4(0,dt)
            self.history.append(y_new)
            self.quant_vec=y_new
            clock_time+=dt
        runtime=time.time()-start_time
        print('\n')
        print('Simulation completed in {} seconds'.format(runtime))
        self.history=np.array(self.history)
    
def nbody_solver(t,y,masses):
    N_bodies=int(len(y)/6)
    solved_vector=np.zeros(y.size)
    distance=[]
    for i in range(N_bodies):
        ioffset=i * 6
        for j in range(N_bodies):
            joffset=j * 6
            solved_vector[ioffset]=y[ioffset+3]
            solved_vector[ioffset+1]=y[ioffset+4]
            solved_vector[ioffset+2]=y[ioffset+5]
            if i != j:
                dx= y[ioffset]-y[joffset]
                dy=y[ioffset+1]-y[joffset+1]
                dz=y[ioffset+2]-y[joffset+2]
                r=(dx**2+dy**2+dz**2)**0.5
                ax=(-c.G.cgs*masses[j]/r**3)*dx
                ay=(-c.G.cgs*masses[j]/r**3)*dy
                az=(-c.G.cgs*masses[j]/r**3)*dz
                ax=ax.value
                ay=ay.value
                az=az.value
                solved_vector[ioffset+3]+=ax
                solved_vector[ioffset+4]+=ay
                solved_vector[ioffset+5]+=az
    return solved_vector

simulation=Simulation(bodies)
simulation.set_diff_eqs(nbody_solver)
simulation.run(365*u.day,1*u.hr)

earth_position = simulation.history[:, :3]  # Extracting position for Earth
sun_position = simulation.history[:, 6:9]    # Extracting position for Sun
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Plot the trajectories
ax.plot(earth_position[:, 0], earth_position[:, 1], earth_position[:, 2], label='Earth')
ax.plot(sun_position[:, 0], sun_position[:, 1], sun_position[:, 2], label='Sun')

# Add labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('X (AU)')
ax.set_ylabel('Y (AU)')
ax.set_zlabel('Z (AU)')
ax.set_title('Trajectories of Earth and Sun')

# Add a legend
ax.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Any gravity effects ? that is what causes the elliptical orbits iirc...

Comment: @SolarMike Hi, the gravitational effect is governed by the nbody_solver method. Specifically,
        ax=(-c.G.cgs*masses[j]/r**3)*dx
calculates the acceleration in the x direction and so on

Comment: If thst is so, what is wrong with either your maths or the solver to give a straight line acceleration?

Comment: @SolarMike that's the question they are asking...?

Comment: @SolarMike

As far as I can tell all of my math checks out. I calculate the difference in x positions via 

'''dx= y[ioffset]-y[joffset]'''

then, using the gravitational acceleration formula, i calculate the acceleration 


'''ax=(-c.G.cgs*masses[j]/r**3)*dx'''

I'm not sure where the issue is

Comment: So how many planets revolve around the Sun - are all the other 8 effects included? If so where?

Comment: @SolarMike I havent included the other planets yet as I cant get Earth to work by itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like its working:
You should probably just give your "Earth" an starting velocity which is perpinducular to your suns gravity. Else the earth will just fly straight into the sun!  (`swap vel_vec=np.array([0, 30, 0])` with `vel_vec=np.array([30, 0, 0])` for example)

```
# set up first instance of a celestial object, Earth
Earth = CelestialObjects(name='Earth',
                         pos_vec=np.array([0, 1, 0]) * u.AU,
                         vel_vec=np.array([30, 0, 0]) * u.km / u.s,
                         mass=1.0 * c.M_earth)
```

[image]

Comment: I actually love you thank you so much. Can you explain why the velocity in x is perpendicular however? Im a bit confused as to why that happens.

Comment: imagine you have an space with coordinates xyz. your earth lies on **pos_vec** =np.array([x=0, **y=1**, z=0]) . if you now set your velocity to **vel_vec** =np.array([**x=0, y=30**, z=0]) it means that your earth is straight flying on the y axis to the sun or away. However if you add speed to the x direction it will not fly in the direction the the center of your sun but it will move perpendicular to the y axis in x direction.  I hope that helps. Just play around with those values or the z values and you will get a feeling.